# Calling a Controller Action from View without changing page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controller, action, jruby

I want to call a controller action from my view. 
My action is called export and essentially I just want to export some data to a csv file which I already wrote the method for.  But when I click this link I dont want any of the stuff currently on my page to change.  What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Use [csv_builder](https://github.com/teambox/csv_builder) to generate the csv. Make a get request to the controller action and have the action respond to csv format

Eg.

```
  def action1
     respond_to do |format|
        format.csv do
          @filename = "filename.csv"
          @output_encoding = 'UTF-8'
          @csv_options = {:col_sep => ','}
        end
      end
  end
```

You need to have a view file named action1.csv.csvbuilder

Comment: I have already written a method that parses my data in the format that i want.  I have an array of hashes so i want to be able to call my method

Comment: Then you can just do `format.csv {render :text => <your data>}`